# Bent arrow (↩) in visual-line-mode

Tags: linum-mode, fringe, visual-line-mode

I would like to see a bent arrow (↩) in the window fringe, when I'm using `visual-line-mode` becuse with no `linum-mode` (e.g. org, md, latex..) I'm not able to distinguish the lines.

References: [LineWrap](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineWrap)

Comment: I'd like to add to this question by asking for something that would work in terminal Emacs, which doesn't have a fringe.  I'd still like to see a similar indication for lines which have been wrapped.  Also, I'd like to customize the symbol used to indicate line wrap when doing `M-x toggle-truncate-lines`.  Currently it's a backslash, but I'd like to change that to the bent arrow, for instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`(setq visual-line-fringe-indicators '(left-curly-arrow right-curly-arrow))`